# SMB share was usable, then disappeared

Tags: samba

I finished configuring samba this morning. I connected to it with my Mac, and I could read directories, open files, and delete them. It was working :-) Then I restarted my Mac, for unrelated reasons, and now I can't open the share again. This is only a couple of hours after I could access it, and I didn't restart the SMB server in that time. The network between the two is fine, because I am logged into the server from the Mac as I type.

This is my Ubuntu machine, something I've just put together for files and backup, and a few common unix services:

```
Linux case 3.16.0-30-generic #40~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 15 17:43:14 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I set up samba, and the relevant results from testparm look like this:

```
[global]
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    server role = standalone server
    map to guest = Bad User
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    unix password sync = Yes
    syslog = 0
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 1000
    dns proxy = No
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    idmap config * : backend = tdb

[open-share]
    path = /mnt/raid/smb-shared
    valid users = james
    read only = No
    guest ok = Yes
```

My Mac is running Yosemite (OS X 10.10.4).

I've restarted the Mac, and I've restarted smbd after setting my smb password again.

If I open Finder on the Mac, under shared I can see "case", the name of the server. If I click "Connect As..." I can enter my name and password. I change the Name entry to "james" from "James", as I imagine smb is case-sensitive. Then I put in my password, and the dialogue box just shakes, as though I had it wrong.

Running sudo smbstatus gives me this:
    james@case:~$ smbstatus

```
Samba version 4.1.6-Ubuntu
PID     Username      Group         Machine                        
-------------------------------------------------------------------


Service      pid     machine       Connected at
-------------------------------------------------------

No locked files
```

I guess that's fine?

What should I try next? I don't know why it stopped working!

Comment: Can you access it from another computer?

Comment: Not possible right now (unless there's a way to do it with an iPad...). I have tried to loop back on the server though:

`james@case:~$ smbclient -L //192.168.1.106`
 
`Enter james's password: `
 
`session setup failed: NT_STATUS_CANT_ACCESS_DOMAIN_INFO`

Comment: OK, it looks like a server issue.  Try reinstalling the server.

Comment: Or at least resetting the configuration

Comment: I Googled NT_STATUS_CANT_ACCESS_DOMAIN_INFO, and at least two pages suggested adding "security = domain" to the parameters. I did that, restarted smbd, ran testparm, and saw the line " security = DOMAIN" (not sure how the change of case happened.

I still get the same message on trying to connect locally with smbclient: NT_STATUS_CANT_ACCESS_DOMAIN_INFO

Comment: have you properly defined your domain?

Comment: I put in "security = domain":


Is it worth trying security = 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: If you put an IP in there, you'd want to use your network IP, 192.168.1.106.  Otherwise you couldn't access it from outside that machine.

Comment: Is defining my domain something that should happen in smb.conf?  I followed the instructions from [an article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20(Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal)%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!), so the only change I originally made to my smb.conf were to add the share. I've since added line "security = domain".

Comment: See my answer below.  That explains why security = domain isn't working.

Comment: You must join the server to a windows domain as said in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from: https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#SECURITY

security (G)

This option affects how clients respond to Samba and is one of the most important settings in the smb.conf file.

The default is security = user, as this is the most common setting, used for a standalone file server or a DC.

The alternatives are security = ads or security = domain , which support joining Samba to a Windows domain

You should use security = user and map to guest if you want to mainly setup shares without a password (guest shares). This is commonly used for a shared printer server.

The different settings will now be explained.

SECURITY = AUTO

This is the default security setting in Samba, and causes Samba to consult the server role parameter (if set) to determine the security mode.

SECURITY = USER

If server role is not specified, this is the default security setting in Samba. With user-level security a client must first "log-on" with a valid username and password (which can be mapped using the username map parameter). Encrypted passwords (see the encrypted passwords parameter) can also be used in this security mode. Parameters such as user and guest only if set  are then applied and may change the UNIX user to use on this connection, but only after the user has been successfully authenticated.

Note that the name of the resource being requested is not sent to the server until after the server has successfully authenticated the client. This is why guest shares don't work in user level security without allowing the server to automatically map unknown users into the guest account. See the map to guest parameter for details on doing this.

SECURITY = DOMAIN

This mode will only work correctly if net(8) has been used to add this machine into a Windows NT Domain. It expects the encrypted passwords parameter to be set to yes. In this mode Samba will try to validate the username/password by passing it to a Windows NT Primary or Backup Domain Controller, in exactly the same way that a Windows NT Server would do.

Note that a valid UNIX user must still exist as well as the account on the Domain Controller to allow Samba to have a valid UNIX account to map file access to.

Note that from the client's point of view security = domain is the same as security = user. It only affects how the server deals with the authentication, it does not in any way affect what the client sees.

Note that the name of the resource being requested is not sent to the server until after the server has successfully authenticated the client. This is why guest shares don't work in user level security without allowing the server to automatically map unknown users into the guest account. See the map to guest parameter for details on doing this.

See also the password server parameter and the encrypted passwords parameter.

Note that the name of the resource being requested is not sent to the server until after the server has successfully authenticated the client. This is why guest shares don't work in user level security without allowing the server to automatically map unknown users into the guest account. See the map to guest parameter for details on doing this.

See also the password server parameter and the encrypted passwords parameter.

SECURITY = ADS

In this mode, Samba will act as a domain member in an ADS realm. To operate in this mode, the machine running Samba will need to have Kerberos installed and configured and Samba will need to be joined to the ADS realm using the net utility.

Note that this mode does NOT make Samba operate as a Active Directory Domain Controller.

Read the chapter about Domain Membership in the HOWTO for details.

Default: security = USER

Example: security = DOMAIN

Comment: I explicitly added "security = user", and changed my smbpasswd, and it's working now. Thanks!